# dns_get_record and nameserver for an IP

Tags: php, dns

As far as I know it is a valid question to ask for a nameserver for a given IP. (Is it really?)

So I tried in Windows command line this:

```
C:\Users\Marty>nslookup
Vychozi server: google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address: 8.8.8.8

> set querytype=ns
> 58.123.112.50.in-addr.arpa
Server: google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address: 8.8.8.8

123.112.50.in-addr.arpa
        primary name server = dns-external-master.amazon.com
        responsible mail addr = root.amazon.com
        serial = 32
        refresh = 3600 (1 hour)
        retry = 900 (15 mins)
        expire = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 900 (15 mins)
```

but when I try to get the same thing in PHP (Windows, PHP 5.4.9):

```
dns_get_record("58.123.112.50.in-addr.arpa", DNS_NS);
```

I just get an empty array.

What is the problem?

Thanks!

**Note:** In both cases the DNS server is 8.8.8.8 (Google).

EDIT:

I tried what Paul suggests:

```
 $ret = dns_get_record("58.123.112.50.in-addr.arpa", DNS_ALL, $a, $b);
```

and the results are:

```
  $ret => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'host' => '58.123.112.50.in-addr.arpa',
      'class' => 'IN',
      'ttl' => 300,
      'type' => 'PTR',
      'target' => 'ec2-50-112-123-58.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com',
    ),
  ),


  $a => NULL,

  $b => NULL,
```

Comment: If you pass in the other two optional params,  `&$authns and &$addtl` are they being populated? Does anything happen if you change your search to DNS_ANY or DNS_ALL?

Comment: I tried DNS_ALL and DNS_ANY, posted above, and I get PTR record (which makes sense) but not the result that nslookup returns.

Comment: Does this work with any other domains? For example what are the results for google.com, amazon.com etc.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but output from my linux box is: 
`*** Can't find 58.123.112.50.in-addr.arpa: No answer`

`Authoritative answers can be found from:
123.112.50.in-addr.arpa
 origin = dns-external-master.amazon.com
 mail addr = root.amazon.com...`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gjTeTyp9 -- results for google.com are OK.

Comment: Paul S: I tried to experiment a little bit with your answer from Linux but it didn't bring me closer to a solution. There must be something obvious that I miss.